# Android Appwidget stops updating when adding second type of AppWidget to App

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have an application which has an Appwidget. All works well.

Now I have decided to add a second AppWidget to my application. I have created a second receiver in my manifest and new provider class etc. I think I have it all wired correctly as I am able to add the new widget to the Homescreen.

But ... now both widgets will never update. I checked my code in debugger and the update methods are getting called, but it seems like the AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(x,y) call is not causing the update to happen.

Update: My App is working fine on API8 emulator, but exhibiting the odd behaviour with API10 emulator.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: Do you need a second instance of the first AppWidget or you create a new AppWidget?

Comment: Yury: I am creating a new AppWidget of a different type.

Comment: I believe this may be related to an Emulator bug:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8160

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed that this is an Emulator bug: App works fine on Froyo and Gingerbread devices, works fine on Fryo Emulator, but exhibits bad behavior in Gingerbread emulator.

Likely related to issue:

[Google code bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8160)